# java.lang.NullPointerException Selenium 2 classes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

My program works fine when run from my local machine with out using selenium grid with Remote Web driver. However when i set up the same test cases using selenium grid with Remote Web driver . Get message in eclipse saying:

```
java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat PP_OBJ_Login.Adminlogin(PP_OBJ_Login.java:38)
at PP_Main.step01_Login(PP_Main.java:86)
```

Now I know the above means that line 38 and line 86 is where the problem is in both classes my problem is i don't know why this is happening when I use selenium grid with Remote Web driver.

```
public class PP_Main {

     private static WebDriver driver;
     private static String homeUrl;
     //private String homeTitle ="Google";
     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
     private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
     private static StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();


     @BeforeClass
     public static void setUp() throws Exception {

      //----------This works and envokes IE browser -------
      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
      DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
      cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());
      cap.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
      cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
      RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://51.19.210.111:5555/wd/hub"), cap);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      String url = "https://wfn-iat.adp.com/public/index.htm";
      driver.get(url);

     }
  @Test
public void step01_Login() throws Exception {
 PP_OBJ_Login.AdminVisiable(driver);
 PP_OBJ_Login.Adminlogin(driver).click();-- -> line 86
 PP_OBJ_Login.UserName(driver).sendKeys("NorfolkAutoUser6@adp");
 PP_OBJ_Login.Submitbtn(driver).click();
 PP_OBJ_Login.Password(driver).sendKeys("iatiat01");
 Thread.sleep(2000);
 PP_OBJ_Login.Submitbtn(driver).click();
 Thread.sleep(5000);
}


PP_OBJ_Login.Java


public class PP_OBJ_Login {

 private static WebElement element = null;

 // WebElement Adminlogin
 public static WebElement Adminlogin(WebDriver driver) {-- -- -> Line 38
  element = driver.findElement(By.id("adminLogin"));
  return element;
 }

 // WebElement input Field
 public static WebElement UserName(WebDriver driver) {
  element = driver.findElement(By.id("USER"));
  return element;
 }
```

I want this to work using selenium grid and remote web driver. Is there any way to resolve the null pointer issue?

Comment: The only other thing i can think of is that private static WebElement element = null; is causing the problem

Comment: I'd bet that "driver" is null. What is the result if you put a System.out.println(driver); right before "element = driver.findElement(By.id("adminLogin"));" ?

Comment: checking to see 1 sec

Comment: and your right it is (null)

Comment: Okay, then you have to find out why. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Selenium itself to give you detailed tips at this point.

Comment: Is there a way around this?I know that this is the problem the only solution is to make driver not null

Comment: Where in your code do you instantiate driver? Can you provide the interesting part? Without 'driver' you won't be able to do anything as every single method derives from it.

Comment: will post it i sec

Comment: I added to my previous post where I instantiate the driver it in my main class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is, that you define 'driver' as a class member but you do not instantiate it. So it is null all the time.

```
 public class PP_Main {

    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static String homeUrl;
    //...
```

And the driver you instantiate inside setUp() is only valid inside the method itself. Although it has exactly the same name it is NOT the 'driver' you defined globally.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {

    // ...

    cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://51.19.210.111:5555/wd/hub"), cap);

    // ...   
}
```

Instantiate it this way instead

```
public class PP_Main {

    private static RemoteWebDriver driver;
    private static String homeUrl;
    //...


   @BeforeClass
   public static void setUp() throws Exception {

        // ...

        cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://51.19.210.111:5555/wd/hub"), cap);

        // ...   
}
```

This should work.

Comment: I will try this