# Inheriting a remote webdriver syntax

Tags: java, selenium, inheritance, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I want to inherit the remotewebdriver from my BaseTest class so all my tests in another class can inherit the webdriver. Currently I only have it implemented in my 2nd class, I can do this quite easily if I am creating the tests locally, but we're utilizing a tool "CrossBrowserTesting" in order to scale our tests. Anyone have any ideas how this would look syntactically?

My attempts to inherit it from the BaseTest class haven't been panning out. It's not the same syntax i'm used to. The documentation is different from what I have provided as well.

```
Class 1

public class BaseTest {
public static String CBUsername = ABCD1;
public static String CBAuthkey = HIJK1;

public static String OS = "Windows 10";
public static String Build = "3";
public static String Browser = "Chrome";
public static String BrowserVersion = "73x64";
public static String Resolution = "1366x768";
public static String RecordVideo = "True";
public static String RecordNetwork = "False";


}

Class 2
```

```
@Test
public void ExampleTest throws MalformedURLException, UnirestException {

DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("name", "Dashboard"); // Set Name To Test Name
caps.setCapability("build", Build); // Set Build To Version Of Release
caps.setCapability("browserName", Browser); //Custom
caps.setCapability("version", BrowserVersion); //Custom
caps.setCapability("platform", OS); //Custom
caps.setCapability("screenResolution", Resolution); //Custom
caps.setCapability("record_video", RecordVideo); //Custom
caps.setCapability("record_network", RecordNetwork); //Custom

RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + CBUsername + ":" + CBAuthkey +"@hub.crossbrowsertesting.com:80/wd/hub"), caps);

try {

/* Set testScore to fail in-case an error is discovered at runtime. */
myTest.testScore = "fail";

/*
 * Enter Code Here
 *
 */

/* if we get to this point, then all the assertions have passed. */
myTest.testScore = "pass";

}

catch(AssertionError ae) {

String snapshotHash = myTest.takeSnapshot((driver).getSessionId().toString());
myTest.setDescription((driver).getSessionId().toString(), snapshotHash, ae.toString());
myTest.testScore = "fail";
} 
finally {

             System.out.println("Test complete: " + myTest.testScore);
             // here we make an api call to actually send the score 
             myTest.setScore((driver).getSessionId().toString(), myTest.testScore);

             // and quit the driver
             driver.quit();

         }
     }
        public JsonNode setScore(String seleniumTestId, String score) throws UnirestException {

        /* Mark a Selenium test as Pass/Fail */
            String username = CBUsername; /* Your username */
            String authkey = CBAuthkey;  /* Your authkey */
         HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.put("http://crossbrowsertesting.com/api/v3/selenium/{seleniumTestId}")
                 .basicAuth(username, authkey)
                 .routeParam("seleniumTestId", seleniumTestId)
                 .field("action","set_score")
                 .field("score", score)
                 .asJson();
         return response.getBody();
     }

     String takeSnapshot(String seleniumTestId) throws UnirestException {
         /*
          * Takes a snapshot of the screen for the specified test.
          * The output of this function can be used as a parameter for setDescription()
          */
        String username = CBUsername; /* Your username */
        String authkey = CBAuthkey;  /* Your authkey */
         HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post("http://crossbrowsertesting.com/api/v3/selenium/{seleniumTestId}/snapshots")
                 .basicAuth(username, authkey)
                 .routeParam("seleniumTestId", seleniumTestId)
                 .asJson(); 
         // grab out the snapshot "hash" from the response
         String snapshotHash = (String) response.getBody().getObject().get("hash");

         return snapshotHash;
     }

     public JsonNode setDescription(String seleniumTestId, String snapshotHash, String description) throws UnirestException{
         /* 
          * sets the description for the given seleniemTestId and snapshotHash
          */
        String username = CBUsername; /* Your username */
        String authkey = CBAuthkey;  /* Your authkey */
         HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.put("http://crossbrowsertesting.com/api/v3/selenium/{seleniumTestId}/snapshots/{snapshotHash}")
                 .basicAuth(username, authkey)
                 .routeParam("seleniumTestId", seleniumTestId)
                 .routeParam("snapshotHash", snapshotHash)
                 .field("description", description)
                 .asJson();
         return response.getBody();
     }
 }



}
```

Comment: You talk about using inheritance but are not using. I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that might help others with a similar question

[java.lang.NullPointerException Selenium 2 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989155/java-lang-nullpointerexception-selenium-2-classes)

```
public class PP_Main {

private static RemoteWebDriver driver;
private static String homeUrl;
//...


@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {

    // ...

    cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new 
    URL("http://51.19.210.111:5555/wd/hub"), cap);

    // ...
```

}